# How do I implement global theme to React Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change specific Material component style, e.g `ListItemText`, In my case I prefer to use `theme` variable, not one time solution, working every material component in app.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        ListItemText: {
            root: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
    }
});



render(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Root store={store} />
        </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
   ,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I tried to override `ListItemText`'s color following official doc (https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type), but not working.

Anything I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the docs [here](https://material-ui-next.com/api/list-item/):

> If using the `overrides` key of the theme as documented, you need to
>   use the following style sheet name: `MuiListItemText`

So your code should be

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiListItemText: {
            root: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/303199d39b42a321d28347d8440d69166f872f27/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L208

Comment: Add a reference of source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/303199d39b42a321d28347d8440d69166f872f27/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L208 

The name is defined here.